# Autowiring fails: Not an managed Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hessian

I have a big problem in my diploma project and would be very glad if you guys could help me!
I made a Maven Multi Module Project and have 3 "Core-projects"

- `NaviClean`: (Parent)
- `NaviCleanDomain`: contains the domain model with all my entities and
  an interface `MeinRemoteDienst` which is needed by `NaviCleanServer`
  and `NaviCleanCleint` for the `Hessianprotocol`
- `NaviCleanClient`: conatins the GUI and a Hessian connection to
  `NaviCleanServer`
- `NaviCleanServer`: Here are my repositories, my connection to the DB
  and the Implementation of the interface `einRemoteDienst`
  `NaviCleanServer` & `NaviCleanClient` have `NaviCleanDomain` in Maven as
  Dependency.

Now every time I try to start the Server on my Tomcat I get the following error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transaktionsRepository': 
Injection of persistence dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
Error loading class [at.naviclean.service.impl.MeinRemoteDienstImpl] for bean with name 'meinRemoteDienstImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Fredy\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NaviCleanServer\WEB-INF\classes\at\naviclean\service\impl\MeinRemoteDienstImpl.class]: 
problem with class file or dependent class; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at/naviclean/service/MeinRemoteDienst
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    ……………….
```

**ModelBase:**

```
package at.naviclean.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MappedSuperclass
public class ModelBase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "ts")
    private Date timestamp;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

**Kassa:**

```
package at.naviclean.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Kassa extends ModelBase {

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "geld")
    private int geld;

    public Kassa(String name, int geld) {
        this.name = name;
        this.geld = geld;
    }

    public Kassa() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getGeld() {
        return geld;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGeld(int geld) {
        this.geld = geld;
    }

}
```

**MeinRemoteDienst:**

```
package at.naviclean.service;

import at.naviclean.domain.Kassa;

public interface MeinRemoteDienst {

    int getKassaCount(int plus);

    String getNameFromKassa(int id);

    Kassa findById(int id);
}
```

**BaseRepository**

```
package at.naviclean.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import at.naviclean.domain.ModelBase;

public interface BaseRepository<T extends ModelBase> extends
        JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    T findById(long id);

}
```

**KassaRepository:**

```
package at.naviclean.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import at.naviclean.domain.Kassa;

public interface KassaRepository extends BaseRepository<Kassa> {
    List<Kassa> findByGeld(int geld);

    Kassa findByName(String name);

    @Query("select k from Kassa k where k.geld = ?1")
    Kassa findByGeld1(int geld);
}
```

**MeinRemoteDienstImpl:**

```
package at.naviclean.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import at.naviclean.domain.Kassa;
import at.naviclean.repositories.KassaRepository;
import at.naviclean.service.MeinRemoteDienst;

@Service
public class MeinRemoteDienstImpl implements MeinRemoteDienst {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public KassaRepository kassaR;

    public int getKassaCount(int plus) {
        return 2;
    }


    public String getNameFromKassa(int id) {
        return kassaR.findById(id + 0l).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Kassa findById(int id) {
        return = kassaR.findById(id + 0l);
    }

}
```

**application-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <import resource="infrastructures.xml" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="at.naviclean.repositories">
        <repository:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="at.naviclean.repositories.BaseRepository" />
    </jpa:repositories>

    <context:component-scan base-package="at.naviclean.service.impl" />

</beans>
```

**infrastructures.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                        </bean>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kassatest" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>


        <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



<import resource="../root-context.xml" />
    <bean id="idMeinRemoteDienst" class="at.naviclean.service.impl.MeinRemoteDienstImpl" />
    <bean name="/MeinRemoteDienstHessian"
        class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter"
        p:serviceInterface="at.naviclean.service.MeinRemoteDienst"
        p:service-ref="idMeinRemoteDienst" />

</beans>
```

**root-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>/MeinRemoteDienstHessian</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>/MeinRemoteDienstHessian</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

***Here is what I already tried:
1. I wrote this test which "went red":***

```
package at.spengergasse.kassa;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import at.naviclean.domain.Kassa;
import at.naviclean.repositories.KassaRepository;

@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class KassaTest {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private KassaRepository kassaR;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void findByIdTest() {
        Kassa k = kassaR.findById(2);

        assertThat(k, is(not(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    public void findByGeld() {
        Kassa k = kassaR.findByGeld1(1200);

        assertThat(k, is(not(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Kassa vorher = new Kassa("ssf", 222);
        kassaR.save(vorher);
        Kassa nachher = kassaR.findById(vorher.getId());
        kassaR.delete(nachher);
        assertThat(vorher.getId(), is(equalTo(nachher.getId())));
    }

}
```

***ERRORS:***

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - 
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@41e22632] to prepare test instance [at.spengergasse.kassa.KassaTest@6639be68]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'meinRemoteDienstImpl': 
**Injection of autowired dependencies failed**; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: public at.naviclean.repositories.KassaRepository at.naviclean.service.impl.MeinRemoteDienstImpl.kassaR; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'kassaRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Not an managed type: class at.naviclean.domain.Kassa**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    ………..
```

***2. I insertet in my persitence.xml my domainmodel an repositories manually. The result was a "green" test but I wasn't still able to start the server...***

Thanks alot in advance!!! I can't imagine what it would be without you :)

Comment: Putting in the whole codebase here! Can you do some base level debugging? Try running Maven with `-X` or `-e` switches to get the Debug Log as well as complete stacktrace.

Comment: I already did this: the problem is that I can't autowire my repository because my domain class is _not an managed type_

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I got an very helpful advice from **Oliver Gierke:**

> The last exception you get actually indicates a problem with your JPA
>   setup. "Not a managed bean" means not a type the JPA provider is aware
>   of. If you're setting up a Spring based JPA application I'd recommend
>   to configure the "packagesToScan" property on the
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory you have configured to the package
>   that contains your JPA entities. Alternatively you can list all your
>   entity classes in persistence.xml, but that's usually more cumbersome.
>
> The former error you got (NoClassDefFound) indicates the class
>   mentioned is not available on the projects classpath. So you might
>   wanna check the inter module dependencies you have. As the two
>   relevant classes seem to be located in the same module it might also
>   just be an issue with an incomplete deployment to Tomcat (WTP is kind
>   of bitchy sometimes). I'd definitely recommend to run a test for
>   verification (as you already did). As this seems to lead you to a
>   different exception, I guess it's really some Eclipse glitch

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone using Spring Boot, the `@EntityScan` annotation can be used. See this answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25368455/854151

Comment: yes on the object LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean use the setPackagesToScan method

Comment: This helped me to uncover that a colleague had misspelled our entity package, causing "Not a managed bean":  'configure the "packagesToScan" property on the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory you have configured to the package that contains your JPA entities'

Comment: Yes this solution worked for me. Thank you @alfred_m. Make sure to set LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean::setPackagesToScan(). In my case i did a typo and entire depedency chain from controller to dao were failing. Make sure to verify the fully qualified package name properly.

Answer (score 10):

You should extend the scope of the component-scan e.g. `<context:component-scan base-package="at.naviclean" />` since you placed the entities in package `at.naviclean.domain;`

This should help you to get rid the exeption: 
**Not an managed type: class at.naviclean.domain.Kassa**

For further debugging you could try to dump the application context (see javadoc) to explore which classes have been detected by the component-scan if some are still no recognized check their annotation (@Service, @Component etc.)

EDIT:

You also need to add the classes to your `persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit>
    <class>at.naviclean.domain.Kassa</class>
     ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice...well I extended of the component-scan but I still get the same exeption :( I don't understand why the testclass is able to manage "Kassa" if I mention it in my persistence.xml

Comment: This is it. Get the EntityManagerConfiguration per desired EntityManager right, set PersistenceUnit and PackagesToScan correctly and do not forget to update application-context.xml to let component-scan reach the entities.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is strugling with the same problem I solved it by adding `@EntityScan` in my main class. Just add your model package to the basePackages property.

Comment: i am new to spring . i don't know how this works but it solved m problem thanks , if possible explain

Comment: @EntityScan is a way to tell Spring directly "Hey, so, I have this entities that you are not finding (probably because these entities belong to another project/dependency), pls look here"

Answer (score 6):

In spring boot I get same exception by using CrudRepository because I forgot to set generic types. I want to write it here in case it helps someone.

errorneous definition:

```
public interface OctopusPropertiesRepository extends CrudRepository
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

successfull definition:

```
public interface OctopusPropertiesRepository extends CrudRepository<OctopusProperties,Long>{
```

Comment: Took me some time, and when i found this answer, i realized that i have overlooked the needed typing, thanks.

Comment: This was my error too. Sadly this answer was too low in the list for me to notice.

Answer (score 4):

For Controllers, `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.school.controllers"})`

For Respositories, `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.school.repos"})`

For Entities, `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.school.models"})`

This will slove

> "Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface"

problem as well as

> Not an managed Type

problem. Sample configuration below

```
package com.school.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.school.controllers"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.school.repos"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.school.models"})
public class SchoolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when using IntelliJ, I had multiple modules in the project. The main module was dependent on another module which had the maven dependencies on Spring.

The main module had `Entity`s and so did the second module. But when I ran the main module, only the `Entity`s from the second module got recognized as managed classes.

I then added Spring dependencies on the main module as well, and guess what? It recognized all the `Entity`s.

Comment: I have the same issue where I have multiple modules and entity classes in first modules are not be recognized, but entity classes in the second module are being recognized. Do you mind explaining what exactly you did to get it working? I am using a spring boot, so do not have any spring dependency config file. I added ComponentScan in the main application class as needed by spring boot. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hello Alice, this might not be the proper way but make sure you have dependencies on spring-boot in both the modules. Which build system are you using? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: I do not use spring boot but I am facing similar issue. The application works fine when deployed on server but gives this "Not an managed type" error when test cases are run.

Answer (score 3):

you need check packagesToScan.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryDB" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDB" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitDB" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="at.naviclean.domain" />
                                            //here
 .....
```

Answer (score 3):

After encountering this issue and tried different method of adding the entity packaname name to EntityScan, ComponentScan etc, none of it worked.

Added the package to packageScan config in the EntityManagerFactory of the repository config. The below code gives the code based configuration as opposed to XML based ones answered above.

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("org.package.entity");
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("default"); 
    emf.afterPropertiesSet();
    return emf.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you extend indirectly JpaRepository ( KassaRepository extends BaseRepository that extends JpaRepository) then you have to annotate BaseRepository with `@NoRepositoryBean` :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends ModelBase> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    T findById(long id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was my actual problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some other poor sod ends up here because they are having the same issue I was: if you have multiple data sources and this is happening with the *non-primary* data source, then the problem might be with that config. The data source, entity manager factory, and transaction factory all need to be correctly configured, but also -- and this is what tripped me up -- MAKE SURE TO TIE THEM ALL TOGETHER! `@EnableJpaRepositories` (configuration class annotation) must include `entityManagerFactoryRef` and `transactionManagerRef` to pick up all the configuration!

The example [in this blog](https://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/) finally helped me see what I was missing, which (for quick reference) were the refs here:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.foobar.bar")
```

Hope this helps save someone else from the struggle I've endured!

Answer (score 0):

Refering to Oliver Gierke's hint:

When the manipulation of the persistance.xml does the trick, then you created a normal java-class instead of a entity-class.

When creating a new entity-class then the entry in the persistance.xml should be set by Netbeans (in my case).

But as mentioned by Oliver Gierke you can add the entry later to the persistance.xml (if you created a normal java-class).

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was quite simple based on what @alfred_m said..... tomcat had 2 jars conflicting having same set of Class names and configuration.

What happened was ..............I copied my existing project to make a new project out of the existing project. but without making required changes, I started working on other project. Henec 2 projects had same classes and configuration files, resulting into conflict.

Deleted the copied project and things started working!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You get the same exception when you pass the incorrect Entity object to the CrudRepository in the repository class.

```
public interface XYZRepository extends CrudRepository<IncorrectEntityClass, Long>
```