# How to specify packagesToScan in HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` directly in a Spring unit test. While Hibernate and `EntityManager` is configured, no entities are scanned.

**Exception**

```
10:29:36.377 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
10:29:36.505 [main] TRACE o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory - Property Sources: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$FlatPropertySources@65f8f5ae
10:29:36.638 [main] TRACE o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory - Property Sources: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$FlatPropertySources@65f8f5ae
10:29:36.716 [main] TRACE o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory - Property Sources: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$FlatPropertySources@65f8f5ae
10:29:36.818 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:29:36.842 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
10:29:36.979 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
10:29:36.980 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:29:36.982 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
10:29:37.234 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
10:29:37.599 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
10:29:37.608 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10:29:37.648 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.a.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
10:29:37.742 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
10:29:37.742 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
10:29:37.744 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000396: Updating schema
10:29:37.745 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

My workaround is to create my own `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` as follows:

```
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("buzzPU"); // persistence.xml
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:META-INF/donotparsepersistence.xml");
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.soluvas.buzz.core.jpa");
```

Note that I don't use `META-INF/persistence.xml`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the Spring Boot reference...

**[62.4 Separate @Entity definitions from Spring configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration)**

Spring Boot tries to guess the location of your @Entity definitions, based on the @EnableAutoConfiguration it finds. To get more control, you can use the @EntityScan annotation, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=City.class)
public class Application {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Use [`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html) and not [`org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html) which is deprecated.

Comment: weirdly `EntityScan` on its own is not enough for me, I also need to set `CoponentScan` as well. But having issues at it only seems to use "first" package it finds with entity classes, and I have a number (from different dependencies).

Answer (score 22):

Using the following also helps:

```
@EntityScan("org.soluvas.buzz.core.jpa")
```

It is an alias for 'basePackages' property that configures a list of packages to scan for annotated entities.

> This annotation provides an alternative to manually setting
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.**setPackagesToScan**(String...)
>   and is particularly useful if you want to configure entity scanning in
>   a type-safe way, or if your LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is
>   **auto-configured**.