# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactUsRepository':

Tags: java, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

I want to create delete row SQL, but when i run my project, i have error,
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactUsRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.oop2.contactus.model.ContactForm

this my code

ContactUsList.html

```
<a th:href="@{'/delete-contact-us/'+ ${contactForm.id}}">Delete</a>
```

MainController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/delete-contact-us/{id}")
    public String deleteContactUs(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
       contactService.delete(id);
       return "ContactUsList";
}
```

ContactService.java

```
public void delete(long id) {
    contactRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

ContactUsRepository.java

```
package com.oop2.contactus.repositories;
import com.oop2.contactus.model.ContactForm;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ContactUsRepository extends CrudRepository<ContactForm, Long> {
}
```

Comment: The exception is telling you what is wrong. -> `Not a managed type: class com.oop2.contactus.model.ContactForm`. Which means `ContactForm` isn't an entity. So either you are using the wrong type, or your packages aren't scanned correctly (like your `@SpringBootApplication` class should be in the `com.oop2` package.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that spring can't find ContactForm because it's not in the default package.
Check that :

[Autowiring fails: Not an managed Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069449/autowiring-fails-not-an-managed-type/33608400)

And

[Spring boot - Not an managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-an-managed-type)